# logo after last word multi-line - Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a title with a fixed width, and I need to set a logo after the last word in the title.

When the title is too long, it takes 2 lines.

Example :

```
My
Title (logo should go here)
```

Here is a codepen with tailwind : https://codepen.io/jbrazillier/pen/OJZWYEb

I can only set it below the title, or on the right of the first word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have **fixed** size for your **h2** you should wrap your image and title in a **relative div** and your logo should be **absolute** then use position **left-full**

by the way you should improve your markup i added the **border** to show you what i mean

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<h2 class="w-[40px] flex text-3xl font-bold border">
  <div class="relative">My title
    <img class="w-8 h-8 absolute bottom-0 left-full" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/Red-circle.svg/1200px-Red-circle.svg.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</h2>
```